# Store Arbitrary values related to mysql record

Tags: design-patterns, database-design, mysql

I have created an app that manages a Data cleansing workflow. Each row imported needs to store an arbitrary number of key value pairs in addition to our standard mysql schema. The key values need to be searchable. I am using rails + mysql currently. What are my options? As of now,  I am just adding a new fields to the rails schema as new requirements arise, I need a way to store extra data for each row that might not apply to any other rows.

Answer (score 1):

Based on the information you have provided, that seems like a new table (KeyValues table that has three columns: foreign key, key, value where the foreign key links this new table to the existing table.

This will allow the following:

1. An arbitrary number of key/value pairs can be stored, which can be indexed and searched and you can join on queries with the records in your existing table(s) if needed.
2. If a row in your existing table(s) does not have any key/value pairs to be stored, then it just wouldn't have entry in this new KeyValues table.
3. This does not impose any restriction on how many keys every row has and would not require a change in the existing table(s)' schema every time a new key has to be added.

Based on the information in the question, I think if you did a [3NF normalization](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Database_normalization), you would most likely end up with this kind of a schema.